# On the independence of multivariate gaussians.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, gaussian

Hello I have some perplexities about independence of multivariate gaussian distributions:
before getting there, I have studied the following results:

1)*Let $m$ r.v $X_1, \dots , X_m$ which range in $\mathbb{R}^{d_1} , \dots , \mathbb{R}^{d_m}$ respectively. They are called **independent** if for every $A_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^{d_1}, \dots , A_m \subset \mathbb{R}^{d_m}$ we have*

$$P(X_1 \in A_1 , \dots , X_m \in A_m) = P(X_1 \in A_1) \dots P(X_m \in A_m)$$

*Also, if $\phi_1 : \mathbb{R}^{d_1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} , \dots, \phi_m:\mathbb{R}^{d_m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ respect some regularity conditions, then $\phi_1(X_1), \dots , \phi_m(X_m)$ are independent*.

Now, let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ independent r.v $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and consider

$$U = 2X_1 - X_2 - X_3 \qquad V = X_1 + X_2 + X_3, \qquad W = X_1 -3X_2 +2X_3$$

What can I say about the independence of r.v $U,V,W$?

The just stated result would bring me to think that these random variables $(U,V,W)$ are all independent (since $\phi$ are here simple linear transformations)..

Of course $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$ where $I$ is the identity $3 \times 3$ matrix. Then $U, V, W$ are jointly gaussian because linear transformations of jointly gaussian, so to check the independence is it sufficient to prove they are not correlated. But it results $Cov(U,W) \neq 0$ so $U,W$ seem not to be independent. Why does the initial statement fail here? Thanks

EDIT:

I guess we would have here $(d_1 = d_2 = d_3 = 3)$,  $\phi_1 : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \mapsto 2X_1 - X_2 - X_3$, $\phi_2 : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \mapsto X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ and last one $\phi_3 : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \mapsto X_1 - 3X_2 + 2X_3$.

So actually, the initial result just tells me that $\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3$ are independent but $U = \phi_1$ and $W = \phi_3$ are not..why?

Comment: $(2,-1,-1)$ is not orthogonal to $(1,-3,2)$ so $U$ and $W$ are not going to be independent.  If instead say $W=X_2-X_3$ then I think you would have independence

Comment: In your introduction you have $\phi_1(X_1), \phi_2(X_2), \ldots$ but then you seem to move to something like $\phi(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, which is not the same sort of thing

Comment: I edited my question with more details..

Comment: You would not expect $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \mapsto X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ to be independent of $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \mapsto X_1 + X_2 + X_3$, so independence will depend of the relationships between the three transformations

Comment: ok but what I'm asking is where does the initial statement fail exactly?

Comment: The initial statement says that if two (or more) random variables are independent, then taking functions of *each* of them cannot lose that independence. This is intuitively sensible. But you are trying to apply this to functions of *all* of them, and there is no reason to think that would work, and in fact it usually does not as shown in your example.

Comment: ok... I think I got it now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand better the concept of independence I would like to consider an example as follows:

suppose that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are iid $N(\theta;1)$

$V=X_1+X_2+X_3$ is a Complete and Sufficient Statistics (CSS) for $\theta$ while

$U\sim N(0;6)$ and $W\sim N(0;14)$

This means that U and V are Ancillary for $\theta$ and thus, calling upon [Basu's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem) $U,V$ and $V,W$ are independent